# CRM SDK - update entity's primary image to another field

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-sdk

I am trying to update the existing entity's `PrimaryImage` attribute programmatically.

I have been trying to access the entity's attributes but couldn't find any regarding PrimaryImage.

Is it even possible to achieve that using CRM SDK request in C#? If yes, how can I achieve it?

I am trying with below approach:

```
var entityMetadata = RetrieveEntityMetadata(service);
entityMetadata.PrimaryImageAttribute = "ps_anotherPrimaryImage";

var updateEntityRequest = new UpdateEntityRequest();
updateEntityRequest.Entity = entityMetadata;
```

[image: compile time Error]

Comment: for images fields you just need to assign the base64 value of the image, did you write some code and is not working?

Comment: @GuidoPreite, I have edited my question to upload the approach.

Comment: so you are trying to change the attribute that is defined as primary image? I don't think it's possible, and honestly I don't see a reason why you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: I am creating the **CRMHelper** project which have main utility which should be able to do all such operations. So it is not achievable at all?

Comment: I am not aware of a project called "CRMHelper", however I checked the documentation and looks like you can change the primary image attribute by setting the property IsPrimaryImage of the field you want to set https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/image-attributes

Comment: I think an entity can only have a single attribute defined as the primary image